# Tridion 2013 SP1 Context Engine - Creating the device database - Timeout

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, ambient-data-framework, context-engine

After installing Context Engine (following the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 live documentation) I found the request to create/update the device database is timing out.

**CLI:** java -Xmx1024m -jar lib\cwd_engine.jar https://context.sdl.com/seed

```
Output: Shutting HSQLDB context repository down : jdbc:hsqldb:file:/<website-path>/lib/../repository/sdl-context-repository;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=5000;hsqldb.ock_file=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc;readonly=false;files_readonly=false;hsqldb.log_data=true;hsqldb.cache_size=1000;hsqldb.cache_rows=5000

Error: Cannot execute context repository manager
com.sdl.context.engine.repository.exception.ContextRepositoryException: Cannot load context knowledge from https://context.sdl.com/seed; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sdl.context.engine.knowledge.ContextKnowledgeLoader.loadFromUrl(ContextKnowledgeLoader.java:242) ~[cwd_engine.jar:1.0.10.3]
at com.sdl.context.engine.knowledge.ContextKnowledgeLoader.load(ContextKnowledgeLoader.java:98) ~[cwd_engine.jar:1.0.10.3]...
```

I suspect this is an issue at the URL end rather than a local issue, but that said, any advice would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to successfully `install/upgrade` the Devices Database your server `ip address` needs to be added to the SDL Whitelist. Please contact to Customer Support or your sales contact in order to have this setup

Comment: That's a real pain for development in a local vm (facepalm), thanks for the information Eric

Comment: Is the device database copyright, if not can somebody post a copy of the ambient database?

Comment: The device database is copyright

Comment: Once you get it downloaded from _one_ authorized IP you can copy it locally (but won't be able to update it automatically). The alternative would be yet another license file or check, which I really preferred to avoid.