# Web 8 DXA 1.5 Java web site failing with "Unable to get response from OData service"

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java

We have the OOTB DXA 1.5 site running happily on a Windows Web 8.1 CM/CIS server but we need it on our Linux (RH 7.2) CIS machine. Not so happy :(

When requesting a page lots of good things happen in the session content log and then we get a failure from Tomcat.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError: Unable to get response from OData service: No Response.

All the service endpoints we can see work fine and none of the microservices are reporting any ERRORs at this time.

So what is Tomcat trying to do when it throws this error?

Answer (score 10):

It turns out this is all to do with encoding.
In each microservice `bin/start.sh` script replace the `JVM_OPTIONS` with this:

```
JVM_OPTIONS="-Xrs -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true"
```

Restart Tomcat, the DXA site works and we are all happy again :)