# Multilanguage with DXA 2.0 SDL Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We have problems setting the second Publication. We used to configure the `cd_dynamic_conf.xml`, but now it doesn't exist in the project. However, it seems that the [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-7D334E4E-72F7-4AAA-B541-7A845E15C88C) is not updated. When we create the new Publication, the Page is not found (404 error). We have followed steps 1, 2, 3 & 4.

Any suggestions?

We published the publish settings page. Are we missing anything more?

**LOG**

> ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Failed to retrieve localization for request url = http://localhost:8080/webextras/es/test/index.html, uri = /webextras/es/test/index.html
>       com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationNotFoundException: Localization not found
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:220)
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:82)
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.isPreview(WebRequestContextImpl.java:105)

We call to the service and we checked that the publication exists.

[image: TtmWebsite]
[image]

Still when accessing:

http://localhost:8080/webextras/es/test/index.html

We get a 404 error. The page is published & the publish_settings as well.

`http://cdservice.com:8182/discovery.svc/PublicationMappings('45')`

**SOLUTION**
When deleting the contextUrl, and let it as root, it works. Does it mean that there's a bug in the product related with contextUrl different to root?

Comment: Please provide the log

Comment: Please provide the output of `Get-TtmWebsite`, `Get-TtmWebApplication` and `Get-TtmMapping` (Topology Manager PowerShell cmdlets)

Comment: Do you still get the `LocalizationNotFound` exception, or is it a `PageNotFoundException` now?

Comment: Did you really deploy your DXA web app with Context URL `/webextras`?  If so, does it work properly if you deploy it as ROOT (and update Topology Manager accordingly)?

Comment: Please share your `_all.json` (see Velmurugan’s Answer below)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your web app URL **http://localhost:8080** not added to your Topology manager website base URL.

If you run **Get-TtmWebsite** and look at the BaseUrls of your website, I would expect that you will not see an entry for http://localhost:8080

To update the BaseUrls, to add http://localhost:8080 you can run

```
Set-TtmWebsite -Id WebsiteId1 -BaseUrls @("http://dev.local","http://localhost:8080")
```

Regarding, Multi-language - Language selector documentation indeed explained correctly.

Try to validate the following steps are correctly setup for the Multi-language language selector.

1. Parent Language publication, double check the highlighted image values are correctly setup as expected.[image]
2. Child language publication, double check the highlighted image values exist or not. [image]

**Note:**
Important to note Site Identifier - used to group publications together to define a single website - should have the same value.

3. Ensure you have set up the publishing business process type in child publication too and then it's configured website publication mapping relative URL in Topology Manager.

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-TtmMapping

   CmEnvironmentId     : TridionCM_localhost 
   PublicationId       : tcm:0-8-1 
   EnvironmentPurpose  : Staging 
   WebApplicationId    : Website1_RootWebApp 
   RelativeUrl         : / 
   PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://localhost:8080/ 
   IsOffline           : False 
   CdEnvironment       :  
   Id                  : Mapping1 
   ExtensionProperties : {}

   PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-TtmMapping -RelativeUrl nl -PublicationId tcm:0-10-1 -WebApplicationId Website1_RootWebApp
   ```
4. Localize to update the **Localization Configuration** component on child publication content level, to change the culture and language values
5. Publish both parent and child publication **Publish Settings** page.
6. Refresh the cache and reload the settings in the Web app by In IIS, recycle your website Application Pool or by accessing http://localhost:8080/admin/refresh?allSiteLocalizations=true
7. Access your website to check the language selector displays or not.
8. You can also double check [DXA-Webapp-Install]\BinaryData\8\system\config_all.json, siteLocalizations has both publication language details. 
   [image]

**Update:**

Discovery Service out-of-sync with Topology Manager then you can force sync the Discovery Service using the **Sync-TtmCdEnvironment** cmdlet

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I still have a doubt, what happens here with the context of the application. I have one publication with two contexts, do I need to create different baseUrls? E.g. http://localhost:8080/app1/es/home/index.html and http://localhost:8080/app2/es/faq/index.html

Comment: No, these are not different Base URLs. See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/web-application-vs-web-site-in-topology-manager/14249#14249

Comment: I still got the 404 error, I updated the question with the results of the topology manager

Comment: double check your broker DB, In the page table URL field has all the pages published with your context-URL start with /webextras/?

Comment: We had to restart the CD microservice to get the new conf from the Topology Manager. Is this a bug of SDL Web?

Comment: No, Discovery Service out-of-sync with Topology Manager then you can force sync the Discovery Service using the Sync-TtmCdEnvironment cmdlet, mainly we use to sync this if we used more than one CME and CD scaled environments we should need to run this sync command. Updated my answer to include this cmdlet.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` should not be needed and Topology Manager changes should be synched automatically. If that doesn’t happen, there may be an issues with your Discovery DB. You could try creating a new one, re-register the Capabilities and then run `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` (one time).

Answer (score 0):

There were Known Issues with running DXA as a non-root Web Application in the past. See also: [PublicationMapping Error occurs on DXA 1.4 Java version, SDL Web 8](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/publicationmapping-error-occurs-on-dxa-1-4-java-version-sdl-web-8)

Full support (and testing) for running DXA as a non-root Web App was an item on the (internal) backlog. IIRC, DXA.NET 1.6+ seemed to work properly as non-root Web App, but we didn’t fully test it.

I’m not sure what the current status is, but if you're having issues getting it to work and you really want to use a non-root Web App, please report an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues). That will put it back on the radar.